# Getting an undefined token of add category in console

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to React and Node and I'm getting an undefined token in console when I add category I get undefined in the console. I am using cookie-parser.

server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const connectDB = require('./database/db');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const categoryRoutes = require('./routes/category');

//middleware
app.use(cors());
//dev specifies it is for development
app.use(morgan('dev'));
//express.json allows us to parse incoming request in json in the format of a json
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
//route for category
app.use('/api/category', categoryRoutes);

connectDB();
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
res.send('Inside Server');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

category.js (controller file)

```
exports.create = (req,res) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        res.json({
            successMessage: `${req.body.category} was created!`
        });
    }, 5000);
};
```

category.js (routes file)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const  categoryController = require('../controllers/category');
const { authenticateJWT } = require('../middleware/authenticator');

router.post('/', authenticateJWT , categoryController.create);

module.exports = router;
```

authenticator.js (middleware file)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { jwtSecret } = require('../config/keys');

exports.authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    console.log(token);
}
```

keys.js file

```
//it is gonna tell us/ signifying if we are live if in develoopment or in production 
const LIVE = false;

if (LIVE) {
    module.exports = require('./prod.js');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./dev.js');
}
```

Console screen:
Instead of undefined i should be getting token.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a `token` Cookie available? (You can check using the inspector of your browser, normally in the „application“ tab. If you are sending the request using any tools like postman, curl, wget, …, you have to set the cookie first.)

Was the cookie available on any other routes? What’s the difference between these routes and the category route? Is it possible that your cookie is constrained to a specific path, e.g. to `/api/auth`? If so, adjust the path in [`res.cookie`.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)

Comment: i have previously also got into trouble with cookie so i used localstorage and stored the token there

Comment: So if I’ve got you right you are storing the token only in local storage? Which, by definition, remains local and is not sent to the server. So if there is no cookie available, you can’t access the token cookies‘ value, right?

Comment: Alternatively, when requesting data from your API in React, you can pass the token using a header field (for [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), using the headers option) and read it in express instead of the cookie: [`req.get("Authorization")`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get)

Comment: i am confused! peviously when user login the website i have created cookie but it doesnot work so i stored the token in local storage

Comment: As am I ;) so are you storing your token as a cookie or in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) _right now _? For the latter, is your snippet posted above up to date?

Comment: These are two very distinct technologies, only having in common the ability to store some piece of information in your browser. Cookies are small chunks, normally set by a Webserver and accessible on each request as they are sent as metadata. Items in Local Storage look pretty much the same, however they are accessible by applications running in the client only, hence their name "local".

Comment: Your code posted above all is nodejs code, running on the server side of your application. Therefore, it has no access to your local storage.
In contrast, I assume you are using React as a framework. This is your client-side code, running in the browser and therefore able to access the local storage.
Now you are sending requests from your client-side application to your server-side application (the routes starting with `/api`). However, you expect the requests to have some kind of authentication with them.

Comment: According to your code posted above, your server expects the cookie „token“ to be filled. But: If you are not setting this cookie (during login, neither from the server-side nor from the client-side), there is no cookie available. If no cookie is available, it can’t be read. And if it cannot be read, it is `undefined`.

Comment: So there are different solutions available to this:
- Revert to using a cookie during login. You can set the cookie using `res.cookie()`, as stated previously.
- Read the token from `localStorage` and pass it on for each request. This can be done either by using a query parameter (`<url>/api/category?token=<token>`, read using [`req.query.token`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) instead of `req.cookies.token` in your authentication.js file) or by adding a custom header to the request (see above for instructions).

Comment: That‘s all I can tell you so far with the information available. If you need further assistance, please update your question with more information regarding the usage of localStorage/cookies, what‘s supposed to be happening with your token (where it comes from, where it should go) and what you actually expect to happen. For any questions regarding the technologies, you can have a look at the linked docs.

Comment: i am storing my login token in local storage and token is made there but not in when i click on add category as because i have stored the token in local storage but not in the cookie so i think the problem is that instead of using cookie i have to use local storage to store the token

Comment: Kindly tell me if there's any dependency like cookie-parser that will work like it but for localStorage?